# How to assign a unique id to a node in d3 collapsible tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

As someone new to d3 and javascript,  I am trying to learn how the collapsible tree works by looking at the version provided by

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Specifically, I do not understand how and why the following statement successfully assigns a unique id to a node after nodes have been updated.

// Update the nodes…

```
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
```

My understanding is that nodes is an array, and this array has an associated index i.
Each time the nodes is updated, the above statement binds the new nodes(as in data) with the nodes on the webpage (as in visual representation) using the unique key value of id derived from the array index i. If an element of the nodes array does not have an id, it will be assigned ++i.

This is where I get confused. Suppose the first nodes array has 4 elements so each element gets an id of 1,2,3, and 4. I collapse the tree and now the new nodes array has 3 elements that happen to be the same first three elements of the first nodes array. These elements have an id of 1,2 and 3. No problem so far.

Now the next updated nodes array has 4 elements with the same first 3 and a different 4th element.
The above code correctly assigns an id of 5 to this 4th element.

My understanding is

1. this last nodes array has 4 elements,
2. index i for this new 4th element = 3, and
3. ++i = 4
4. As a result, the above statement should have assigned an id of 4 to the 4th elements.

But the code assigns id=5 instead. And when I check the value of i in the firebug debugger, i goes up to 4, remains at 4, and then goes to 5 for the above scenario.

Can someone explain what is happening with the above code and where my faulty understanding lies?

Thank you.

Comment: use i++ to get what you want.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. `i` is a global variable and not an array index here, maybe that's where your confusion comes from?

Comment: Yes, there it's an index -- made explicit in the function declaration `function(d, i)`. If that solves your problem, I could post an answer with some more explanations.

Comment: Thank you, that explains my question. I had thought i was a special d3 variable since it says in the https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data in the paragraph # selection.data([values[, key]]) that "To control how data is joined to elements, a key function may be specified. This replaces the default by-index behavior; the key function is invoked once for each element in the new data array, and once again for each existing element in the selection. In both cases the key function is passed the datum d and the index i." Is this i  different from the global i? Thank you.

Comment: It's poor coding style, that's all, using `i` for a persistent counter variable when we're so used to seeing it in a similar context as the local index variable.  As @LarsKotthoff says, the version of `i` that gets used depends on the function declaration -- if you declare a function parameter with a certain name, that will mask any outside variables with the same name.  However, I would recommend giving the counter variable a different name so that there is no confusion!

Comment: Thank you,  @AmeliaBR.  I changed the global i to totalnodenumber.

Comment: Thank you also @LarsKotthoff. Sorry my previous entry to which you replied got deleted. I was referring to the code from another tutorial http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html with the lines     function redraw() {

  var rect = chart.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data, function(d) { return d.time; });

  rect.enter().insert("rect", "line")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i + 1) - .5; })

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` used in the particular example you're referring to is, as opposed to almost all other D3 examples, a global counter that keeps track of how many nodes have been seen. In many other cases, you would see code like

```
.attr("something", function(d, i) { ... })
```

or

```
.data(data, function(d, i) { ... })
```

In all of these cases, `i` refers to a variable local to the function -- the index of the data element within its array. This is passed by D3 and a *completely different* `i` than the one in the example you're referring to.

It might help to understand the example better if you replace all occurrences of the `i` with `counter`.